# How to prevent onClick if another button was clicked before

Tags: java, android

I have 4 buttons which change the direction (Up, Right, Down, Left) of movement of a View.
The movement is called like this:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            move();
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
```

I want to prevent the user to change direction if the previous direction was the opposite. But in my app it is possible when you move right to press up and then left very fast which leads to the view moving left. The desired behaviour would be that the view moves up in this case and not left.

This is how `move()` looks like:

```
public void move() {
    switch(direction) {
        case 'N': moveUp();
            break;
        case 'E': moveRight();
            break;
        case 'S': moveDown();
            break;
        case 'W': moveLeft();
            break;
    }
}
```

This is `onClick()`:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonUp:
                if(direction == 'S') {
                    break;
                }
                direction = 'N';
                break;
            case R.id.buttonRight:
                if(direction == 'W') {
                    break;
                }
                direction = 'E';
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDown:
                if(direction == 'N') {
                    break;
                }
                direction = 'S';
                break;
            case R.id.buttonLeft:
                if(direction == 'E') {
                    break;
                }
                direction = 'W';
                break;
        }
    }
```

How can I check the direction in which the view actually moved? Saving the previous value in a separate variable does not work, as you can just press the buttons very fast and the value of the variable would not have the right value.

I already tried to add a handler with `postdelayed()` for `onClick()` which didn't work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to save the previous move direction in the actual `move()` method. So your `move()` method could look like:

```
public void move() {
    switch(direction) {
        case 'N': if (lastDirection != 'S') moveUp();
            break;
        ...
    }
    lastDirection = direction;
}
```

Oh, and please create an Enum for the direction. You'll find it's much better to use than Chars.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me. It should be `if (lastDirection != 'S')`

Comment: Right, sry, fixed.